# How to upload files to a Amazon S3 bucket subfolder via POST?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, plupload

I'm using plupload 1.4.2 to upload files directly to an Amazon S3 bucket. The question is, how can I upload them to a subfolder directly? What parameters should I configure in the policy or plupload object config?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Amazon S3 there is no concept of folder or subfolder. Only objects. And an object has a key.

If you wanna upload a file to a folder or subfolder, simply put the object key like this:

```
$key = "folder/subfolder/filename.extension";
```

And Amazon S3 will create the (imaginary) folder(s) and subfolder(s).

Comment: If you are doing the `$key` as a hidden field in a form, you can do something like `name="key" value="folder/${filename}"`.