# How to upload file to S3 Bucket/directory

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I need to upload a file to my S3 Bucket, inside a specific directory. I've used the aws-sdk-go package and was able to upload the file using `PutObject` function inside my bucket. The file will be located in `bucket/root` directory.

What I need to do is to upload it inside `bucket/root/subDirectory` and I'm not able to figure that one out.

**Current Upload Function**

```
_, s3Err := s3.New(s).PutObject(&s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket:               aws.String(envs.InitAWSEnvs().AWSS3Name),
        Key:                  aws.String(fileDir),
        ACL:                  aws.String("private"),
        Body:                 bytes.NewReader(buffer),
        ContentLength:        aws.Int64(size),
        ContentType:          aws.String(http.DetectContentType(buffer)),
        ContentDisposition:   aws.String("attachment"),
        ServerSideEncryption: aws.String("AES256"),
    })
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm not able to figure that one out"? This is not a useful problem description. What exact problem are you facing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload files to a Amazon S3 bucket subfolder via POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512523/how-to-upload-files-to-a-amazon-s3-bucket-subfolder-via-post)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a not-so-common gem that might be useful to a lot of people, the `path.Join` function.

So mainly, the `Key` object of `PutObjectInput` parameter inside `PutObject` function call will have a value of `aws.String(path.Join(path_to_directory, fileName)` instead of `aws.String(fileName)`